# Files missing with soapcpp2 version 2.8.1

Tags: c++, linux, gsoap

I have a application that must communicate using SOAP with a SmartServer, which is a embedded device. The SOAP messages it accepts are without the namespaces but gSAOP sends them with namespaces. So they look like this:

```
<ns3:List>
 <ns3:iLonItem>
  <ns3:xSelect></ns3:xSelect>
 </ns3:iLonItem>
</ns3:List>
```

Instead of this:

```
<List>
 <iLonItem>
  <xSelect></xSelect>
 </iLonItem>
</List>
```

I first tried changing the qualified in the WSDL and XSD files to unqualified and then regenerating the files, and changing unqualified to qualified. But the best what i got is

```
<ns3:List>
 <iLonItem>
  <xSelect></xSelect>
 </iLonItem>
</ns3:List>
```

Which looks better, but still the lists are with the namespaces.

Then I found [this](http://cateof.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/default-namespace-gsoap-with/) site stating that I must use the SOAP_XML_DEFAULTNS option, so I tried. This didn't work in the beginning but then I found out I have to use version 2.8.1 instead of 2.7.9l-0.2 (the standard version of Debian). So I uninstall-ed the Debian version and downloaded 2.8.1 and copied the files. But now when i try to generate files with soapcpp2 the following files are missing: soapClient.cpp, soapClientLib.cpp, soapProxy.h and a lot of *.req.xml and *.res.xml files. I need especially the soapClient.cpp file to compile my project.

I tried the standard binarys from the gsoap/bin directory and rebuilding the src and wsdl files from the gsoap directory as described in INSTALL.txt , but none of this works as I want to.

Can anybody help me a bit further?

For if it matters I'm using Debian Linux version 5.0.8 (Lenny, old-stable) 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question:

...the following files are missing: soapClient.cpp, soapClientLib.cpp, soapProxy.h and a lot of *.req.xml and *.res.xml files. I need especially the soapClient.cpp file to compile my project.

According to the link http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc8 (see section 9.1)
it looks as if you may have used the wrong option set for the call to soapcpp2.  Are you sure you did not specify "Generate server-side code only" by using the -S switch?  For client side only you would use the -C.  For both server and client side files, no switches are required.  Also, generating the proxy files requires that -i be used.

Hope this helps,
Ryyker